# Can't assign value to a variable inside a for loop

Tags: c

**Here is what I want to do:**

- Read all characters from a '.c' file and store that into an array.
- When a character from that array is '{', it will be pushed into a stack. And count of pushed characters will be increased by 1.
- When a character from that array is '}', stack will pop and the count of popped characters will be increased by 1.
- Compare those two counts to check whether there is a missing '{' or '}'

**Here is my code:**

```
int getLinesSyntax(char s[], int limit, FILE *cfile)
{
   int i, c, push_count = 0, pop_count = 0;  
   int state = CODE; 
   int brackets[limit]; 
   char braces[limit]; 

   for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
      braces[i] = 0; 
   }

   for(i = 0; i < limit - 1 && (c = getc(cfile)) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
   {
      s[i] = c;

      if(s[i] == '{')
      {
         braces[0] = s[i]; 
         //push(s[i], braces); 
         ++push_count; 

      }
      else if(s[i] == '}')
      {
         pop(braces);
         ++pop_count; 
      }
   }

   //Mor shiljih uyed array -n togsgold 0-g zalgana 
   if(c == '\n')
   {  
      s[i] = c;
      i++; 
   }
   s[i] = '\0';
   i = i -1;  //Suuld zalgasan 0 -g toonoos hasna

   if(c == EOF)
   {
      //just checking 
      for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
         printf("%d", braces[i]); 
      }
      if(push_count != pop_count)
      {
         printf("%d and %d syntax error: braces", push_count, pop_count);
      }
      return -1; 
   }
   else
   {
      return i; 
   }        
}
```

**Here is the output**

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

**The problems is:**

- Assignments inside the for loop is not working. (It's working when I put that outside of the loop)

I would like to know if there's something wrong with my code :).

Comment: Is really at 0-index in `braces` which you want to put `s[i]` value?

Comment: have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: @The Mask - No, But I just wanted see whether it's working or not.

Comment: @Matt Coubrough - I am using Dev C++ to compile my codes. But I have no idea how to debug my code. (By the way I'm just beginning to learn C from the book by Kernighan and Ritchie)

Comment: Learning to debug is an *essential programming skill*. Asking a question here is not a replacement for debugging. There are tutorials for debugging with DevC++. Please do some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems. 
Lets go through it step by step

1) Your array initialization loop:

```
int brackets[limit]; 
char braces[limit]; 

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    braces[i] = 0; 
}
```

You declare the array having size of `limit` but only initialize 100 items. Change 100 to limit to fully initialize it depending on the parameter of the function.

2) The conditional statement of the main for loop:

```
i < limit - 1 && (c = getc(cfile)) != EOF && c != '\n'
```

Although the first substatement is correct I have two remarks:

Firstly `(c = getc(cfile)) != EOF` might be one reason why the loop is never accessed and still everything is `000000...`. Check if the file exists, the pointer is not NULL or other silent errors occured.

Secondly the `c != '\n'`. What if one of these characters occurs? In this case you won't continue with the next iteration but break out of the entire forloop. Remove it there and put it in the first line of the body like this:

```
if(c == '\n') 
{
    i -= 1; // to really skip the character and maintain the index. 
    continue;
}
```

3) `s[i] = c;`

Can you be certain, that the array is indeed sizeof `limit`?

4) Checking for curly braces

```
if(s[i] == '{')
{
    braces[0] = s[i]; 
    //push(s[i], braces); 
    ++push_count; 
}
else if(s[i] == '}')
{
   pop(braces);
   ++pop_count; 
}
```

You assign to `braces[0]` always, why?

5) Uninitialized access

```
if(c == '\n')
{  
    s[i] = c;
    i++; 
}
s[i] = '\0';
i = i -1;  //Suuld zalgasan 0 -g toonoos hasna
```

You're now using the function-global variable `i`, which is never initialized properly for this block. What you do is to use a variable that is used basically everywhere ( which is basically also no problem from the memory point of view. ), but you rely on legacy values. Is this done by purpose? If no, reinitialize `i` properly. I have to ask this since i can't read your comments in code.

What I'm quite unhappy about is that you entirely rely on one variable in all the loops and statements. Usually a loop-index should never be altered from inside. Maybe you can come up with a cleaner design of the function like an additional index variable you parallelly increase without altering `i`. The additional index will be used for array access where appropriate whereas `i` really remains just a counter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this condition "c != '\n'" which is breaking the for loop right after the first line, before it reaches any brackets. And hence the output.

Comment: Are you sure?  The idiom looks OK to me.  If the first character is `a`, then it is not EOF and it is not `'\n'`, so the body of the loop will be entered, won't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The problem however is that the check for the line break will break evaluation too early. I think the intention was to skip all linebreaks and not evaluate them. This might stop everything unintentionally.

Comment: So the loop will break without even the entire file being read as it breaks at the end of the first line.

Comment: OK; the code is doing one sane thing — but not the same sane thing as the comments say it is supposed to do.  Yes, the code breaks at the first newline; I assumed that was intentional, but on further study, it is not what the question says is required.

Answer (score 0):

For the task of counting whether there are balanced braces in the data, the code is excessively complex.  You could simply use:

```
int l_brace = 0;
int r_brace = 0;
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == '{')
        l_brace++;
    else if (c == '}')
        r_brace++;
}

if (l_brace != r_brace)
    printf("Number of { = %d; number of } = %d\n", l_brace, r_brace);
```

Of course, this can be confused by code such as:

```
/* This is a comment with an { in it */
char string[] = "{{{";
char  c = '{';
```

There are no braces that mark control-of-flow statement grouping in that fragment, for all there are 5 left braces (`{`) in the source code.  Parsing C properly is hard work.

Comment: I didn't know it was this simple :). Thanks for your answer.